# AVAudioSession setCategory WithOptions

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

If I set an AVAudioSession category by enabling some options (by using [setCategory:withOptions:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/setCategory%3awithOptions%3aerror%3a)), and later I call setCategory:error: , what happens to the previously set options?

1. Do they keep their state?
2. Are they all reset to their respective default value?

If the answer is #1, what happens if the new category is not compatible with the enabled option? Is it automatically disabled by the system?
I tried to read the documentation, but I couldn't find that particular info.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options don't keep their state when a category change occurs.

The categoryOptions property of your applications AVAudioSession shared instance is assigned a value of 0 when there are no options set using either of the setCategory methods currently available.

For example this line -

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

is equivalent to -

```
AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionsNone = 0;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionsNone error:nil];
```

Comment: I just tested this and this is totally wrong. Options **do not get updated** when the method without them is called.

Comment: Looks like it does not work for me as I am running iOS 10 developer beta 8. I filed a bugreport to Apple. I hope they fix it.

Comment: I see this bug also on iOS 9